# Merge two time machine backups into one folder

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have two time machine disks from two macs, first disk has Backups.backupdb/mac1 and the second Backups.backupdb/mac2. How can I merge these backups into one? Or in other words, copy Backups.backupdb/mac2 to first disk?

There is a similar question about archaving old backups [Consolidate and Archive Old Time Machine Back-ups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340242/consolidate-and-archive-old-time-machine-back-ups) But I'd like to continue backing up both macs on one disk.

**UPD**: Another similar question
[Migrate a Time Machine backup in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274414/migrate-a-time-machine-backup-in-terminal/323691) But again, the goal is different, I need both backup folders fully suitable for backing up.

**UPD2**: There is one more similar question [Merge Time Machine Backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/merge-time-machine-backup) although it solution with `SuperDuper` is not really suitable for me because `SuperDuper` seems to work on disk level, not on file/directory level.